# HikariCp change password dynamically after setPassword

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, hikaricp

I developed a spring boot restfull aplication that talk with db2 .

I used Hikari datasource for good pooling handling (maybe)

The password is taken from a safe system and for each getconnection i set the password that i recieved from the safe.

the reason why i set the password for each connection is because that The password can be changed in the safe Once a week at an unknown time so i must before get connection to get the new password and set it instead the exist.

the problem is that the Hikari keep the old password even if the pool empty and i give the new password

any idea how can i change the password for each get connection ?

> this is the configuration file for Hikari

```
#maximum number of milliseconds that a client will wait for a connection
spring.datasource.connectionTimeout=20000
#minimum number of idle connections maintained by HikariCP in a connection pool
spring.datasource.minimumIdle=0
#maximum pool size
spring.datasource.maximumPoolSize=100 
#maximum idle time for connection
spring.datasource.idleTimeout=30000
# maximum lifetime in milliseconds of a connection in the pool after it is closed.
spring.datasource.maxLifetime=0 
#default auto-commit behavior.
spring.datasource.autocommit=true 
spring.datasource.poolName=db2Pool
```

> create the dataSource

```
 @Bean("dataSourceMF")
    @Order(PriorityOrdered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public DataSource dataSourceMF() {

       PasswordsMessage passwordsMessage = passwordApi.getPassword("username");
       String userPassword = passwordsMessage.getPassword();

        Properties configProps = new Properties();
        configProps.put("poolName", poolName);
        configProps.put("jdbcUrl", db2Url);
        configProps.put("driverClassName", db2Driver);
        configProps.put("username", db2User);
        configProps.put("catalog", db2Catalog);
        configProps.put("maximumPoolSize", maximumPoolSize);
        configProps.put("minimumIdle", minimumIdle);
        configProps.put("connectionTimeout", connectionTimeout);
        configProps.put("idleTimeout", idleTimeout);
        configProps.put("autoCommit", autoCommit);
        configProps.put("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSize", 250);
        configProps.put("dataSource.prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", 2048);
        configProps.put("dataSource.cachePrepStmts", Boolean.TRUE);
        configProps.put("dataSource.useServerPrepStmts", Boolean.TRUE);
        configProps.put("password", userPassword);

        HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig(configProps);
        dataSource = new HikariDataSource(hc);

        return dataSource;
    }
```

> get connection

```
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException, Exception {
        
        PasswordsMessage passwordsMessage = passwordApi.getPassword("username");
        String userPassword = passwordsMessage.getPassword();
    
        try {
            dataSource.setPassword(userPassword);
            return dataSource.getConnection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

> pom.xml

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you found a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to find the exact time when the password was going to reset. In my case we are using AWS SecretManager bind with RDS, and password was auto-rotated based on cron expression at 00:00 on the first day of the month. I created scheduler which fetch password just after it was get auto-rotated and update in hikari.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "2 0 1 * *"")
public void autoRotatePassword() throws Exception {
    HikariDataSource datasource = (HikariDataSource) dataSource();
    HikariConfigMXBean hikariConfigMXBean = datasource.getHikariConfigMXBean();
    
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Start refreshing passowrd in %s...", hikariConfigMXBean.getPoolName()));
    hikariConfigMXBean.setPassword(getPassword());
    
     HikariPoolMXBean pool = datasource.getHikariPoolMXBean();
     if (pool != null) {
          pool.softEvictConnections();  // Close unused cnxns & mark open ones for disposal
          pool.resumePool();    // Re-enable connections 
    }
}
```

Where getPassword() contains the mechanism for fetching the password from the SecretManager.

Comment: You dont have to evict the existing connection. Even after the password expire existing connections hold valid.